# Setting Bitmap File Location

Tags: c#

I am trying to take a screenshot of the desktop, and then save it using Bitmap like this

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
bmp.Save("img" + i + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

(the +i is just to add a number at end of picture file name)

How could I make it so the photo gets saved to a file path such as the TEMP directory instead of the location of the executable. Thanks :)

Comment: If you have a specific path in mind (not a special system path like `TEMP`) you just specify the path in your string, so `@"C:\MyFolder\img" + i + ".png"`.  Note that the `@` is there so you don't have to escape the back slashes.  If you are specifically looking for the `TEMP` path, see the answer that's already been created.

Comment: A path *such as* temp? Or *just* temp? Because there's a way to get special folders like desktop, AppData, temp, etc. and then there's a different way to get literally the users temp folder only. Or do you mean "any arbitrary folder" where temp is just an example?

Answer (score 2):

To get a temp filename you can do:

```
string target = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "img.bmp");
```

Comment: if you do not wish to set the name of the file in the second parameter, you can also try:

`string target = Path.GetTempFileName();`